# Simulate reboot to clear tmp on the Windows Linux subsystem

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been using the Windows Linux Subsystem quite intensively for LAMP development. I notice how my SSD was filling up and after running WinDirStat I found that `/tmp` was over 30GB in size! Is there a way how a can simulate a reboot to clear `/tmp` or some other method to prevent the tmp folder growing to huge sizes?

Comment: Just clean it up manually? The better idea would probably be to have a look what's being stored there that causes such huge/so many temporary files.

Comment: Currently doing just that. First delete was rather hard, as `rm` was getting so long it got a too many args error.

Comment: `rm -r ./*` or `rm -r /tmp/*`? Of course it's favorable to first check what's in there and be a tiny bit more precise but it would work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands - but already fixed that. I'm currently looking for a cleaner solution than manually deleting tmp ever other day or setting a cron to do it.

Comment: Ah, sorry. But as for your question you already seem to know the answer as well: A cron job. But as I mentioned it would potentially be better to figure out why there are so many files/such huge files because it does sound somewhat odd. Did you have a look at the files to get an idea of where they're coming from?

Comment: A ok thanks. No unfortunately I did not but only running a LAMP setup, so options and what may have caused it are limited.

Comment: Please look at a few of the files.  What are they named?  What's inside them?

Comment: You can add `rm -rf /tmp/*` at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file, and it will clear `/tmp` every time you start the Linux command line.

Answer (score 10):

## FSTAB - Doesn't work as expected on WSL1, but may work correctly on WSL2

The best approach is to make sure your `/tmp` directory is a temporary mount, **but this doesn't work as expected on WSL**.

Edit your `/etc/fstab` file (with admin permissions, i.e. `sudo vi /etc/fstab`)

Add the following line

```
tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   noexec,defaults,nodev,nosuid,noatime,size=256m  0 0
```

Now close all bash terminals and re-open.

On closer inspection for WSL1, this seems to be creating a new /tmp mount for each bash terminal, hence **does not work as expected**. Specifically, opening a new WSL1 terminal after another has already been established orphans the original /tmp mount (with it still taking up space) and then creates a new one. Earlier WSL1 terminals seem to point to the new /tmp mount, and lose anything saved in the /tmp mount prior to the new WSL1 terminal opening.

## Mount in `.bashrc` - Recommended for WSL1

The recommended suggestion is to mount in the `~/.bashrc` if not already mounted. This seems to work for me

```
mount|grep -E "^[^ ]* on /tmp " >/dev/null
if [ "$?" != "0" ];then
        echo "Mounting tmp"
        sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp -o noexec,defaults,nodev,nosuid,noatime,size=256m
fi
```

Comment: The `fstab` is working for me.  I'm not sure if I'm not checking properly, but if I close with `wsl --shutdown` the `/tmp` folder is cleared, and any other instance shares it until the shutdown.

Comment: @adn The problem with the fstab is it created a new tmp mounts every time you load a new bash console. That's far from ideal, so I switched to using the detection in method in the .bashrc and have added a couple of service launches in there, too.

Comment: */etc/fstab ... this seems to be creating a new /tmp mount for each bash terminal*
@SEof could you please write how to test it?

Comment: @Massimo sure: Open WSL terminal; Put file in `/tmp` mount; Verify file is there with `ls` command; Open second WSL terminal; Verify file is there with `ls` command (it won't be); Verify file is there with `ls` command on first WSL terminal (it won't be). It's actually worse than it appears, as each `/tmp` mount still exists as far as windows space allocation is concerned, and only gets flushed upon full WSL closure, which doesn't occur properly until a full windows reboot due to the mount type of the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: Though, the effect of the mount type keeping WSL running in the background even when all terminals have been closed is actually really useful.

Comment: I already updated */etc/fstab* and *wsl --shutdown* to stop Ubuntu-18.04. From the DOS prompt I type *wsl*, Ubuntu starts up and I type *touch /tmp/provola* Now from DOS prompt I enter a new *wsl* and *ls /tmp* lists the file.

Comment: I type another *wsl --shutdown* and restart with *wsl* : the file */tmp/provola/* is gone. For me /tmp on tmpfs declared in */etc/fstab* works fine. WINDOWS 10 20H2 build 19042.1165. WSL2 running UBUNTU 18.04.5 LTS, kernel 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2.

Comment: Ah, it could be a WSL1 only issue. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with WSL1 until USB device debugging is sorted in WSL2, then I have the fun of trying to switch over and move all my projects from a windows folder to a WSL2 folder...

Comment: works hella fine in WSL2, thanks mate :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [tmpreaper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/tmpreaper.8.html) - it is a tool designed exactly for regular cleaning of /tmp of unused files. In many Linux distros it is installed by default.

At installation a cron job should automatically be set up to run tmpreaper every day. By default, it removes files and subdirectories that haven't been used for 7 days, except for several "protected" names like for example `/tmp/lost+found`. You can change this value in `/etc/tmpreaper.conf` config file.

Comment: WSL does not use a traditional init system and does not run any services by default, including cron daemons.

Comment: @DanielB then one can call `/etc/cron.daily/tmpreaper` from wherever convenient

Comment: Well sure _one can_. However, to make this a good answer, you should provide a complete solution that will work for the OP, not just part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the excellent suggestion from @raj above, you can get `tmpreaper` to run at WSL startup time as follows:

Define a task in Windows Task Scheduler that runs the following command when I log in (to Windows):

> `c:\windows\system32\wsl.exe --user root --distribution ubuntu /etc/init-wsl`

(you know where this is going...)
In distribution `ubuntu`, create a file `/etc/init-wsl`:

> `tmpreaper 96 /tmp`

(my own version of this file also starts dbus, avahi-daemon and xrdp so I have a stable DNS name to connect to....)